# bundler 自体をローカルにインストールする方法

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

プロジェクトによって同じ ruby バージョンでも Gemfile.lock にかかれてる bundler version が違うことがあって困ってます

そういう状態にしてしまうことにも問題があると思うのですが

bundler 自体をプロジェクトごとのローカルディレクトリにインストールして
リポジトリごとにしばることはできないのでしょうか

bundle install にはパスが指定できるのですが gem install の際にパスを指定するにはどうすればいいんでしょうか

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gemで入れたコマンドを実行する際gemのバージョン番号を`_`で囲って引数で渡すとバージョンを指定して実行できます。

```
% bundle _1.17.3_ --version
Bundler version 1.17.3
% bundle _2.1.0.pre.1_ --version
Bundler version 2.1.0.pre.1
```

`gem install` の引数に `-v` でバージョン番号を指定すると、特定のバージョンのgemをインストールできます。

```
% gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
```

プロジェクトごとのローカルディレクトリにインストールせずとも、上記の方法でbundlerのバージョンをリポジトリごとに切り替えて使うことができると思いますが、どうでしょう?

Comment: 素敵です！　早速試してみます！

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ、これは質問への直接の答えになっていない気がしたのでもう1つ回答追加しておきました。

Answer (score 3):

GEM_HOME という環境変数を設定しておくと、そのディレクトリ配下に gem がインストールされます。

Answer (score 0):

RVMを使っている場合、Gemsetsという機能を使うと使用するgemをインストールする場所を分けて切り替えることができます。
https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics

rbenvだとプラグインのrbenv-gemsetで同じようなことができます。
https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset